# Browser tends to download PHP files instead of displaying them, while using XAMPP for Linux

Tags: php, xampp

I am using [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) for Linux, but when I try to open a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) file saved in a folder saved in home directory, the browser downloads the PHP file instead of displaying it. What could be the problem?

**XAMPP Status is:**

```
Component                        Status         Hint
MySQL database                   ACTIVATED
PHP                              ACTIVATED
Perl                             ACTIVATED
Common Gateway Interface (CGI)   ACTIVATED
Server Side Includes (SSI)       ACTIVATED
PHP extension »OPcache«          DEACTIVATED    See FAQ
PHP extension »OCI8/Oracle«      ACTIVATED
```

Some changes to the configuration sometime may cause false negative status reports.

What could be a possible solution?

Comment: is the phpmyadmin and index.php of xampp working fine?

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you try to access a PHP file saved in your home folder, it will be downloaded instead of saved. Just move it to your www folder commonly found in `/var/www` and give it `644` permissions and try again.

Answer (score 1):

check `php.ini`

You might be using short tag `<? ?>` or `<?= ?>` instead of `<?php ?>`.

The `short_open_tag` should be On.

```
short_open_tag = On
```